# Excel - Modifying Field Value Based on Newest Field Update

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm creating a spreadsheet that will help us keep track of how many accounts are sold for that day of the month. For instance, say A1 has a value of 1, A2 has a value of 2, but then A3 reduces back to 1 because a client cancelled our service. We added one account and subtracted one account, so I would want the net number of accounts for that month to display in A30.

Is there a basic formula I can use to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your A column is calculating a running total as it is, if it increments by each sale and decrements for each cancellation, you would then just use this formula in cell A30

```
=INDEX(A1:A29, COUNTA(A1:A29), 1)
```

You could simply put in each row the number of accounts sold i.e. 1, 2 etc. and for cancellations -1, then you would just need to use

```
=SUM(A1:A29)
```

in A30 to show the net value for the day.